# Verificar o valor de início de uma variável

Tags: php

Quero checar se o valor inicial de uma variável é "tal". Como posso fazer isso? Segue um exemplo para melhor entendimento:

```
<?php

$teste = "(51) 3212-3212";

if ($teste =="(51)%") {
    echo "DEU CERTO!";
}

else {
    echo "DEU RUIM!";
}
?>
```

Comment: vc quer pegar só o ddd e comparar?

Comment: Opa. Isso. Quero saber se o inicio da variável corresponde a tal valor, mediante a isso, imprime na tela uma informação. Como no exemplo que coloquei, o valor da variável $teste é  (51) 3212-3212, então quero que quando essa variável comece com (51),  não importa o que venha depois desse (51), uma informação seja visualizada na tela. Entendeu?

Comment: Usa o substr do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php.

Comment: Excelente deu certo amigo. Obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil, não precisa adicionar na pergunta a solução, basta aceitar a resposta. [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/5878)

Comment: Outra maneira seria usando expressão regular http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/e6rmen/1

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `strpos`. Ela vai te retornar a posição em que determinada `string` foi encontrada na sua variável `$teste`. Se retornar `0`, significa que essa string está no início.

```
$teste = 'minha string';

if (strpos($teste, 'minha') === 0) {
      echo "'minha' está no início";
}
```

Traduzindo a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php):

```
int strpos ( string $palheiro , string $agulha [, int $posição ] )
```

> Retorna a posição numérica da primeira ocorrência de `$agulha` dentro de `$palheiro`.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta. Valeu desse jeito caiu bem em outra coisa q vou fazer.

Comment: @Carlos se resolveu o problema, por favor, considere marcar a resposta que lhe ajudou.